# Regex javascript - match either or

Tags: javascript, regex

Using javascript and `.match()` can I simplify this regex?
I want to match against a alphanumeric code of 5x5 or 3x5 blocks that is seperated by hyphens.

For example I want to match:

`123EF-12B45-123H5-A2CGE-A2345`

or

`54321-ABCDE-F2345`

So far I tried `(\w{5}-){4}\w{5}` to match the first example and `(\w{5}-){2}\w{5}` to match the second. Is there a way to match either or? I tried combining the with `|` but it only matched the 3 pairs.

Or is it better to run regex `.match()` twice for each pattern?

Comment: Can you show us how exactly you tried to combine them?

Comment: use two separate regular expressions. The code will be more readable and easier to maintain. Stop trying to cram too much into one regular expression that is impossible to understand.

Comment: I just tried this in a Javascript console and combining them seems to work okay for me. Are you sure you're combining the regexes correctly? Can you post the exact code you are using?

Comment: I matched against the smaller pairs first, so it couldn't catch the bigger one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> (\w{5}-){2}\w{5}|(\w{5}-){4}\w{5}
> ```

The alternation `|` will first try to match the left subexpression, and when that fails it tries the right one. When the left one includes the right one, it will never match the right one. In your case it will stop at only three groups even if there are more. Try to simply exchange them:

```
(\w{5}-){4}\w{5}|(\w{5}-){2}\w{5}
```

You also could combine them into one:

```
((\w{5}-){4}|(\w{5}-){2})\w{5}
(\w{5}-){2}((\w{5}-){2})?\w{5}
```

Comment: This was my problem. I forgot that regex was greedy. Can I also add `\b` to the end of a group to avoid partial matches?

Comment: Not here, because `-` makes a word boundary as well. But string end `$` or a lookahead `(?=\s|$)` should do the trick, your approach is correct.

Comment: Almost there! I tried `((\w{5}-){4}|(\w{5}-){2})\w{5}(?=\s|$)`, which matches as expected. But adding (?=\s|^) before the pattern, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You would need [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) there which is not supported by javascript. But I don't think you would need that anyway unless you need to avoid matching the end of a 4+-repetition. If you're matching exact strings, just put a string beginning `^` before your alternation, if you are matching inside a string `(^|\s)` should do it but you need to strip the whitespace from the result. See also http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: Alright, thank you again for your response. I'm sticking with your original answer and not make it overly complicated with workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
^(\w{5}-){2}\w{5}((-\w{5}){2})?$
```

`(\w{5}-){2}\w{5}` matches the 3x5 case and optionally there can be two more blocks, which would be the 5x5 case.

Alternatively you could use

```
^(\w{5}-){2}((\w{5}-){2})?\w{5}$
```

i.e. put the optional block in between, or a simple combination of your expressions:

```
^((\w{5}-){4}\w{5})|(\w{5}-){2}\w{5})$
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try specified range for blocks with hypen:

```
(\w{5}-){2,4}\w{5}
```

And this (unfortunately or not) also will match 4x5 block, i.e.

```
54321-ABCDE-F2345-ABF45
```

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me:

```
"123EF-12B45-123H5-A2CGE-A2345".match(/(\w{5}-){4}\w{5}|(\w{5}-){2}\w{5}/)
=> ["123EF-12B45-123H5-A2CGE-A2345", "A2CGE-", undefined]

"123EF-12B45-123H5".match(/(\w{5}-){4}\w{5}|(\w{5}-){2}\w{5}/)
=> ["123EF-12B45-123H5", undefined, "12B45-"]
```